# use HTTP and HTTPS for my website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

Both HTTP and HTTPS working depends on what user types in browser.
Example I have a website named http :// example . com and it is working and live, then i want to make it work for something like https: // example . com.

if the user typed

```
http: //example .c om
```

it will work, likewise

```
https: //example .c om
```

I have htaccess file like this

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.html
```

I have tried using this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT}s ^(443(s)|[0-9]+s)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=askapache:%2]
```

this

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https: // example. com/$1 [P,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http:// example . com/$1 [P,L]
```

and this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:https]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=ps:http]
```

still not working. I can only access http but https I can't.
that example.c o m is only a simple web page and does not include any security risks.
there are whitespaces on my link because I can't post more than 1 link

Answer (score 0):

To redirect from http to https, you can use the following Rule :

```
RewriteEngine on


#Check if we are already not on https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
#Then, redirect http to https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: Upon trying, yes it redirects but 404 not found.
Is it possible to whatever http or https is written in url, no redirect but it will work the same, display the same?

Answer (score 0):

HTTPS is not something simply enabled via htaccess, it needs to be enabled and configured on your webserver using a signed SSL certificate. If you are using a hosting provider such as [bluehost](https://www.bluehost.com/) or [hostgator](http://www.hostgator.com), you will need to contact their support team to get HTTPS set up on your site. Otherwise:

1. Get a certificate [here](https://www.startssl.com/) or [here](https://letsencrypt.org/)
2. Learn to install on [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html) or [NginX](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html) webservers

Comment: Okay, I will now first get certificate and will give a feedback right after I tried this. thank you

Comment: Do you know where and how can I access the httpd.conf in my cpanel? can't find it. I have a certificate self assigned on my domain, I just cant access the httpd.conf file

Comment: From cPanel's documentation, here is the process: [Activate and Manage SSL on Your Website (HTTPS)](https://documentation.cpanel.net/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1507653). There is the possibility that your web hosting provider has disabled these options. If that is the case, you will need to contact them about whatever process they have in place to handle SSL.